# Overwriting Javascript Keywords

Tags: javascript, keyword

I know that `delete` is a keyword in JavaScript. So I have this code (for example):

```
var user = {
   create : function () {
       // Create a user account
   },

   delete : function () {
       // Delete a user account
   }
};
```

The above works (barring older versions of IE), so my question is - is it a good idea. Obviously the call `user.delete();` is much clearer to someone utilizing the code than something like `user.delete_one();`

Obviously keywords are important, but on a case by case basis is it alright (granted I don't need legacy IE support) to use this method, or is there a better solution?

Comment: You're not overwriting a keyword, but defining an object property of the same name. `delete` will continue to work as usual.

Comment: Avoid reserved words. And this one isn't really obvious (delete generally does something very different from what you can do with a function here).

Comment: @Sirko - That was my thought. I've never had any issues in the past doing this as long as I'm not redefining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code will work as expected, because you are not overwriting JS keyword. If you try to declare a keyword as variable or function name, JS will show error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete`.

It 's alright with the way you choose but don't override JS  keywords directly.

Comment: Well, you can redefine `await` and `let`

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
var user = {
   create : function () {
       // Create a user account
   },

   'delete' : function () {
       // Delete a user account
   }
};
```

Or by using double quotes `"`

Comment: Indeed, I think some people recommend quoting ALL property names.

Answer (score 5):

Don't attempt to overwrite keywords.  IMO this is bad practice and would be very confusing for another developer.  Rather than having a delete function you can simply rename it to `remove`

Comment: But if you're not redefining the original keyword is it an issue? Plus I would think if I had the following methods: `create`, `modify`, `etc...` logic would point me to `delete` as a logical method.

Comment: @Fluidbyte since you're actually not redefining the keyword you should be fine, however for best practice I would try and stay away from doing it. For instance, Create, modify delete could be rewrote as: Add, edit, remove

Answer (score 3):

When you are using an [object literal](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5), then a property name can be any of the following:

> *IdentifierName*
>   *StringLiteral*
>   *NumericLiteral*

`StringLiteral` and `NumericLiteral` should be clear. What exactly is a `IdentifierName`?

Lets have a look at [section 7.6 of the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6):

> *IdentifierName* ::
>        *IdentifierStart*
>        *IdentifierName* *IdentifierPart*
>
> *IdentifierStart* ::
>        *UnicodeLetter*
>        `$`
>        `_`
>        `\` *UnicodeEscapeSequence*
>
> *IdentifierPart* ::
>        *IdentifierStart*
>        *UnicodeCombiningMark*
>        *UnicodeDigit*
>        *UnicodeConnectorPunctuation*
>        `<ZWNJ>`
>        `<ZWJ>`

So, an `IdentifierName` really is any character sequence as described above. Whether is a reserved word does not matter.

The names you can use for variable and function names are called `Identifier`s and are defined as:

> Identifier ::
>         *IdentifierName* but not *ReservedWord*

You see, reserved words are *explicitly* excluded as possibilities for identifiers, but not for object properties.

**However**, you never know how "good" a parser is and if it adheres to all rules. Additionally, linting tools such as [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) will usually warn you of the use of a reserved keyword, despite the fact that it is valid.
To be on the safe side, you should put such words in quotes and even use bracket notation to access it:

```
var foo = {'delete': ... }
foo['delete'] = ....;
```

If this is too cumbersome, just don't use a reserved word as property name. For example, instead of `delete`, you could use `remove`.